# Select text from between two characters in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, charindex

I have data in database an example of data below

```
folder/subfolder/file/doc
folder/subfolder/doc
```

how do I get the 1st instance of characters from between the '/'

I want to extract `'folder/subfolder'`

I have tried the following but not what I need. this gets 'folder/'

```
LEFT([Cat], CHARINDEX('/', [Cat]) ) as 'doc_cat',
```

and the below gets the last part

```
RIGHT([Cat], CHARINDEX('/', [Cat]) ) as 'doc_cat2',
```

I want to get the 1st part of and second part of string

Comment: How you want to handle border cases? Like `folder/subfolder` or `folder` or is always at least two `/` for each data?

Comment: You say ***between the '/'*** then give the example `folder/subfolder/doc` => `folder/subfolder`?  But `folder/subfolder` isn't ***between the '/'***, only `subfolder` is...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select left(doc_cat_1, charindex('/', doc_cat_1) - 1)
from t cross apply
     (select stuff(cat, 1, charindex('/', cat), '') as doc_cat_1
     ) v1;
```

The string handling capabilities of SQL Server are pretty lousy.  `Apply` at least makes it easier to handle intermediate results.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - The OP's example and the OP's wording contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`

```
LEFT([Cat],charindex('/',[Cat],charindex('/',[Cat])+1)-1) AS 'doc_cat'
```

Comment: This work ok with provided sample data http://rextester.com/DAO60288. But  not sure how should handle border cases like `folder/subfolder`

Answer (score 0):

One more way to accomplish using `XML` -

```
declare @s table(patterns nvarchar(100))
insert into @s 
values ('folder/subfolder/file/doc'), ('folder/subfolder/doc'),('folder/subfolder')
select cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(patterns, '/', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[1]','varchar(100)') + '/' 
     + cast(concat('<x>', REPLACE(patterns, '/', '</x><x>'), '</x>') as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(100)') 
from @s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on SQL 2016 or newer, you could use [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT cat, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY cat) rn
FROM someTable CROSS APPLY
     STRING_SPLIT(cat,'/')
)
SELECT cat, value FROM cte WHERE rn = 2;
```

The advantage here is that rn could be any number you need.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9d7cb/1) here.